# Java ftp.listFiles() get an empty Array

Tags: java, ftp, arraylist

i get an empty Array back from ftp.listFiles(). I tried something. If i change the Type to passive mode, i get the same error, Array is empty. If i run the code on a other machine, the problem is still the same. if i use a windows FTP Client (LeechFtp or WIndows Command Line) i can browse an get the directorylist. If i run the code without the changeWorkingDirectory-Command, i will get the Filelist from ftp root but i don´t get the List from subdirs.

```
ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.setDefaultPort(21);
ftp.connect("ftp.myftpsite.com");
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftp.login("username", "password");
ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("pub/inbound");
FTPFile[] files = ftp.listFiles();
System.out.println(files.length);
```

The ftp.changeWorkingDirectory returns TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

If:

1. you're using an old version (pre 1.5) of Apache Commons Net;
2. the files that you can't list have yesterday's (29 Feb) timestamp;

then you're probably running into this bug: [`FTPClient#listFiles` returns null element when file's timestamp is "02/29"](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NET-188).

Upgrading Commons Net should make the problem go away.